# How to add vertical scrolling and horizontal navigation in android test app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am vey new to Android . As part of my project i have to make a screen which looks like the whatsapp screen.

I mean i have to show list of contacts , that i have added . it should be vertically scrollable . Like in whatsapp when we can swipe left and right to go to Contacts & Call log screens . Similarly i have to add two horizontal navigation buttons on my screen . When you click left navigation button , it will show another screen at the place of my first screen . When you again click left button , it will show the next screen on the hierarchy.

I wanted to know about a general idea , to achieve this .
is there some standard widget for all the horizontal navigation and vertical scrolling in android .
I know we use xml to create the layouts of the screen . I am not sure about the horizontal navigation , i mean how to show another screen when user clicks left or right navigation button .

Answer (score 0):

Use listview in fragments of sliding tabs.